# process large text file using python multiprocessing

Tags: python-multiprocessing, pool

http://www.ngcrawford.com/2012/03/29/python-multiprocessing-large-files/
I want to create a dictionary of a large text file using multiprocessing and I found this.But I have some questions about the parameters that author uses in this code:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
```

what's the parameter of Pool? In other words, what does "4" mean?

```
for chunk in grouper(10, test_data):
```

what does "10" mean

Comment: Consider changing the title of your question to something that covers what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Pool(4)` means that you start a pool of four worker processes.

The argument of `grouper` is explained in the function definition on that web page:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
    """grouper(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') -->
    ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','x','x')"""

    return izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)
```

The output list will consist of chunks of each `n` elements.